# Calling a HTTP service within a JPA/JTA transaction - transaction integrity

Tags: rest, jpa, ejb, jta, bean-managed-transactions

I have a JSF/EJB/JPA application which uses container managed persistence. There is
one case where a call is made to an external service via HTTP which has a cost, this
cost being allocated back to the requesting user. In the current implementation the
process of making the HTTP request is performed by a EJB timer method running periodically
in the background.

The timer method may have to deal with a number of requests in one invocation, although
each request needs to be treated independently, independently with respect to allocating
the cost back to the user, that is. If user A doesn't have enough credit to purchase a
book, this musn't prevent the successful purchase of a book by user B resulting in their
balance being debited due to a rollback.

To provide control over the transaction demarcation for independent processing of each
request I'm using bean managed transactions for the class in which the timer method
resides. This is a java-pseudo-code version of what I've got now:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MessageTimer {
  private void processMessages(UserMessage msg) {
    tx.begin();
    em.joinTransaction();

    try {
      userData = em.find(..., PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

      if(user has enough credit) {
        debit cost from user;

        status = make external http request to order book from supplier;
        if(status == success) {
          commit = true;
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception) {
      tx.rollback();
    }

    if(commit) {
      tx.commit();
    }
    else {
      tx.rollback();
    }
  }
}
```

So the idea is that I start a transaction, assume success and debit the cost from the
user, call the http service and commit if it succeeds or rollback otherwise.

I have an uneasy feeling that I may not be anywhere near the right ballpark with this
design, particularly having the lengthy http call (actually done using jax-rs) inside
the pessimistic_write transaction. I wondered if I could firstly, within a transaction
debit the user (begin/debit/commit), make http call, then credit the user if any error
happens, but there's no transaction integrity.

This is new territory for me, can anyone point me in the right direction, is there an
established way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Many Thanks.

p.s. I'm using a glassfish 3.1 stack with Seam 3

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how jax-rs communication layer is. if the communication is single threaded, then the code you have written is a long running transaction. which might make your application slower.

I am not a tech guru, but what i can suggest is -

Credit the account and make the jax-rs call on a thread. on that case the transaction will be closed before sending the call to remote node. and it will not be a long running transaction, so the application will be faster.

Comment: Hi, I'm running in the EJB container so can't use threads I think. I need the result of the http call to determine whether a cost has been incurred, so I'm not sure what options I have. It is a long running transaction, sure, but I don't see a way around it.